# How to get the id of the block I clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the id of the block I clicked on, then convert the id to a class **and use that class in other functions and method**s.

```js
var tabName = $("tab-1");
tabName = findIdEl();

function findIdEl() {
  var element
  $('.tabs-inpts').on('click', function(e) {
    element = e.target.id;
  });
  return element;
}

console.log(tabName); // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-1" checked>
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-2">
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-3">


<form class="tab-1 tab" name="form" method="post">
  ***other content***
</form>
<form class="tab-2 tab" name="form" method="post">
  ***other content***
</form>
<form class="tab-3 tab" name="form" method="post">
  ***other content***
</form>
```

Comment: `findIdEl()` just adds the event listener and returns `undefined`. The input has not been clicked yet to update 'element', when you do the console.log(). You have to do the logging inside the click event, so that it will log when the element is clicked, not when the page is loaded.

Comment: Do you realize that the click is asynchronous? The code does not sit and wait around for a click to happen and then continue. It assigns the event handler and moves on.

Answer (score 1):

You seem a little confused about how event handlers work in JS and jQuery. You should bind your events when the content loads. You also cannot return anything from an event handler, and it shouldn't be inside a function call.

To make this work you should put all your logic in a single event handler which you bind to all the `.tabs-inpts` elements. Then you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element which was clicked, read its `id`, and use it as a selector to find other elements by class. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $tabs = $('.tab');

  $('.tabs-inpts').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(this.id);
    $tabs.removeClass('foo');
    $('.' + this.id).addClass('foo');
  });
});
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-1" />
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-2" />
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-3" />

<form class="tab-1 tab" name="form" method="post">
  other content
</form>
<form class="tab-2 tab" name="form" method="post">
  other content
</form>
<form class="tab-3 tab" name="form" method="post">
  other content
</form>
```

Comment: Okay. But when I click the second time on the same input this event is called 2 times and so on, how do you advise to fix it?

Comment: I fixed it by $(this).off(e);

Comment: That does not happen with my example above, only with your original implementation using the flawed function call